# How to match a single Capital 'A' plus 8 digits long number with regex?

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-4

I need the user to a single letter 'A' plus 8 digits and no more. Eg. A00000000

Here is my code below kind of works but I want to limit the number of digits to 8. I am using MVC 4.

```
[RegularExpression("^[A][0-9]{8}$", ErrorMessage="Required format: A00000000")]
```

Although it does validate the user can keep typing forever. So there is no limit on the number of characters. It would be nice to stop the user from entering once it hits the maximum of 8 digits.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Your requirements and your regex match.Your issues dont fit in

Comment: `^A\d{8}$` is more concise.

Comment: Show some code so we can see where you've gone wrong. As vks says, the regex is right, so it's a problem with your input logic.

Comment: Are you asking how to make whatever program you're writing in whatever language actually stop taking keyboard input once the user has typed in something matching that pattern? That is an _entirely_ different question, and you will need to tell us the language and post your code that is not working as you expect.

Comment: I updated my post with some code.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to limit the number of characters using regex alone, but you could use the `maxlength` attribute to specify the maximum number of characters allowed in your `<input>` element:

```
<input type="text" name="myInput" maxlength="9">
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you implement it yourself, a regex match can only operate on a string you have. And you won't have it before the user has typed it.

So if you want to prevent him from typing, you're going to have to do it *before* you get to the regex.

Comment: How can I do that. I am using RegularExpression("^[A][0-9]{8}$") with MVC.

Comment: Probably not with the RegularExpression feature of your MVC. Try looking for a more direct length limitation control.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to stop someone from typing more on something like say a textbox on a webpage, you would have to hook into the keypress event (keyup or keydown). Then once the validation fails, return "false" from the keypress event handler and it will stop the character from entering the textbox, or you may need to use preventDefault on the incoming event object (e.g. e.preventDefault()). If you're using jQuery, have a look at this webpage: https://api.jquery.com/keypress/ on how to set the event handler.